# Atom entry with C#

Tags: c#, .net, atom-feed, atompub, syndication-item

How can I make an Atom entry with C# and .NET 4 ?

I need to make an entry with this structure:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:f="XXX:aaa">
  <title>title1</title>
  <summary>summary1</summary>
</entry>
```

I tried to do this with SyndicationItem class but entry contains more info than I need:

```
SyndicationItem atom = new SyndicationItem();
atom.Title = new TextSyndicationContent("test1", TextSyndicationContentKind.Plaintext);

atom.Summary = new TextSyndicationContent("summary1");
atom.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("f", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"), "XXX:aaa");


XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "  ";
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(sb,settings);
atom.SaveAsAtom10(xml);
xml.Close();
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

And the result is:

```
<entry xmlns:f="XXX:aaa" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>uuid:34381971-9feb-4444-9e6a-3fbc412ac6d2;id=1</id>
  <title type="text">title1</title> 
  <summary type="text">summary1</summary>
   <updated>2010-10-29T14:02:48Z</updated>
</entry>
```

How can I create atom entry object without ,  and type="*" to make it look exactly I want?

Can you help me to simplify the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it yourself?

Either use the built in features in .Net:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Or the Argotic Syndication toolkit:

- http://argotic.codeplex.com/

**Edit**

Sorry, missed the part where you use syndication item. Anyway here is some text from the ATOM specification (RFC4287 Section 4.1.2):

- atom:entry elements **MUST** contain exactly one atom:id element
- atom:entry elements **MUST** contain exactly one atom:updated element

In other words: You'll break the standard if you remove those items.

Comment: This is exactly what am I trying to do, I use syndicationitem object, but I can't make it to create the entry I want, but thanks for argotic I'll try that. But it is better to use syndicationitem because it is already in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

According the XML schema:

> Be sure that if you specify a value for only the minOccurs attribute, it is less than or equal to the default value of maxOccurs, i.e. it is 0 or 1. Similarly, if you specify a value for only the maxOccurs attribute, it must be greater than or equal to the default value of minOccurs, i.e. 1 or more. **If both attributes are omitted, the element must appear exactly once**.

```
                    <xs:element name="id" type="atom:idType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="updated" type="atom:dateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
```

`id` is `atom:textType` .Here is snippet of the schema for `textType`:

```
<xs:complexType name="textType" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            The Atom text construct is defined in section 3.1 of the format spec.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" >
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                <xs:enumeration value="text"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="html"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="xhtml"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="atom:commonAttributes"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

So as you can see, **id and updated elements are mandatory and is illegal to omit them**.

On the other hand, type is optional since default value for the `Use` is optional. But I dont know a way to hide it.

Comment: Ok, it seems that SyndicationItem generates right atom entry. Thanks! And how can I simplify the code and remove <id> and <updated> fields?

Comment: I have update. Sorry I was wrong, the attribute was optional.

Comment: May be there is an option for SyndicationItem to remove it?